# How to count the number of occurrences of a specific value in a column in SQL without doing two SQL calls

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table: **Judges**(JName char(25), LawSchool char(25)).

I'm trying to retrieve the number of judges that attended Harvard and the number of Judges that attended Yale in one SQL Call. I know that I could do this

SQL CALL 1)

```
select LawSchool, count(*) as cnt from Judges where LawSchool = 'Harvard'
```

SQL CALL 2)

```
select LawSchool, count(*) as cnt from Judges where LawSchool = 'Yale'
```

But is there not a way I can retrieve the number of Judges who attended *Yale* and the number of judges who attended *Harvard* in **one** SQL call but store them in two variables such as cnt and cnt2?

Comment: Your syntax is not valid in SQL Server, so I removed the tag.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select LawSchool, count(*) as cnt 
 from Judges 
 where LawSchool in ('Harvard','Yale')
 Group By LawSchool
```

Comment: Great! Thanks John!

Comment: @Yusha Happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `group by` clause to separate the aggregate result per unique value:

```
SELECT   LawSchool, COUNT(*)
FROM     Judges
WHERE    LawSchool IN ('Harvard', 'Yale')
GROUP BY LawSchool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use in and group by

```
select LawSchool, count(*) as cnt 
from Judges where LawSchool in ( 'Harvard', 'Yale')
group by LawSchool
```